# R slows down tremendously when writing to Excel in a loop using Openxlsx

Tags: r, excel, performance

I have a function which returns a list of 64 data frames, one large (525 rows, 3000 columns), and the other 63 small (10 x 10). I wrote some simple code to write the dataframes to Excel (see below), and repeated the code 64 times (not elegant, but it works):

```
    options("openxlsx.numFmt" = NULL)
writeData(wb, Sheetname, "Full Algorithm: Number well", startCol = 6, startRow = 1)
writeData(wb, Sheetname, "Threshold", startCol = 8, startRow = 2)
writeData(wb, Sheetname, "Criteria met", startCol = 1, startRow = 8)
writeData(wb, Sheetname, df_tmp[[2]], startCol = 2, startRow = 3, rowNames = TRUE)
```

The code runs in about 20 minutes - not great, but tolerable. I observed that the dataframes grouped naturally into sets of 3, so i tried writing 21 loops, e.g.

```
  options("openxlsx.numFmt" = NULL)
  headers = c("Full Algorithm: Number well", 
              "Full Algorithm: Number unwell",
              "Full Algorithm: % well vs Threshold (x) and # Criteria met (y)")
  
  for(j in 2:4){
    if(j==4){   options("openxlsx.numFmt" = "0.0%")}
    writeData(wb, Sheetname, "Criteria met", startCol = 1, startRow = 13*(j-2) + 8)
    writeData(wb, Sheetname, df_tmp[[j]],    startCol = 2, startRow = 13*(j-2) + 3,  rowNames = TRUE)
    writeData(wb, Sheetname, headers[j-1],   startCol = 6, startRow = 13*(j-2) + 1)
    writeData(wb, Sheetname, "Threshold",    startCol = 8, startRow = 13*(j-2) + 2)
  
  }
```

To my surprise, the program now takes 6 hours to run, and all the time seems to be spent writing to Excel in these loops. Does anyone have any thoughts as what might be happening, and where I ought to look for this extraordinary drop in performance? I'm at a complete loss to explain it.

Sincerely

Thomas Philips

Comment: xlsx code is very slow. It's XML code. So you're finding and inserting lines in a strange way. Memory allocations (and moving chunks of data to new allocations) are intrinsically slow.  Why can't you join your data in R first with something like `bind_rows` and then create the xlsx workbook one time?

Comment: I deliberately did not use bind_rows, as the dataframes are of different sizes, and some require text and derived statistics to be written  under them. I wonder if would it be any faster if I wrote to a csv file, though I suspect I will still have to move all the chunks of data around.